# Lexer command 'more' in antlr doesn't match the expected value

Tags: command, antlr, lexer

I've been using different lexer modes in antlr and I've been encountered problems with the 'more' command in the lexer, as it doesn't match everything inside this respective token. To make things more clear, here is what my code looks like roughly:

```
//DEFAULT_MODE
fragment A: ('A'); //same done for A-Z
KEYWORD_CLASS: C L A S S;
NUM: [0-9];
KEYWORD_SMTH: S M T H->mode(NUMBER_MODE);


mode NUMBER_MODE;

NUMBER: NUM+ ->mode(ANOTHER_MODE);
NO_NUMBER: ~[0-9]->more, mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

Now when I try to test the parser rule

```
rule: KEYWORD_SMTH NUMBER? CLASS;
```

then I'm expecting to match the following phrase:

> SMTH CLASS

But for some reason the first letter of the C is not matched to the Token. I have to type something   like

> SMTH gCLASS

in order to match the keyword CLASS. If I understand correctly, the 'more' command will match everything that is not a number and bring it back to default mode, so it can be part of another token. Can someone please tell me where my mistake is? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you omitted the rule that skips/hides spaces, this is what happens when tokenising `SMTH CLASS`:

1. token `KEYWORD_SMTH` is created for the text text `"SMTH"`
2. the mode changes from `DEFAULT_MODE` to `NUMBER_MODE`
3. the beginning of a token is created for the text `"C"` (`NO_NUMBER...`)
4. the mode changes from `NUMBER_MODE` to `DEFAULT_MODE`
5. inside the `DEFAULT_MODE`, the `"C"` previously matched is glued to whatever `"LASS"` is tokenised as (note this will NOT match the `KEYWORD_CLASS`!)

So, assuming that `"LASS"` is tokenised as an `IDENTIFIER` token or similar, you will have ended up with 2 tokens:

1. `KEYWORD_SMTH` (text `"SMTH"`)
2. `IDENTIFIER` (text `"C"` + `"LASS"`)

Comment: Thank you for your help! So there is no way to get the content of NO_NUMBER to match a keyword from DEFAULT_MODE?

Comment: No, the lexer will not put the `"C"` back in the char stream so that `KEYWORD_CLASS` can be created in the `DEFAULT_MODE`. You will have to move `KEYWORD_CLASS: C L A S S;` in the `NUMBER_MODE` in that case.

Comment: You really should get rid of `~[0-9] -> more`, which IMO is way to broad. Consider editing your question (or creating a new one) where you explain the bigger picture: from the 2 questions you have posted, I'd say your use of lexer modes is overkill, and are making your life more complicated than it should be without them.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I need to write a parser for JCL and because I'm not allowed to use semantic predicates or Java code in general, I felt like lexer modes were the only available option I have to avoid ambiguities. That is why I basically use lexer modes for every parameter of JCL statements that I have to parse. I'll try to explain the bigger picture in a different question.

Comment: Had a quick look at JCL, and yeah, if you don't want semantic predicates, then I see the need of lexical modes (or better: modes are
 preferable to predicates).